# Adding a class to dynamic Bootstrap Table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I want to add a class to my table rows except the header but I can't figure out how to do it. Does somebody know how i can do this?

this is my table:

```
<table id="table" class="hidden table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="variant">Variant</th>
            <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and this is currently where i add the data and want to add the classes to the rows

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: returnValue
});
```

Comment: you are using bootstrapTable plugin, dont you think that peice of information is useful to solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** add `tbody`  tag in html `table`

**2nd :** simple add the class for you `tbody tr` only  like this

```
$('#table tbody tr').addClass("newclass");
```

**HTML :**

```
<table id="table" class="hidden table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="variant">Variant</th>
            <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  //tbody added here  
        <tr>
        ....
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**In jquery**

```
$('#table tbody tr').addClass("newclass");
```

Answer (score 5):

look at the bootstrap table documentation and use the row style properties,
I'm not familiar with that plugin but I guess it should be something like this

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: returnValue, 
    rowStyle :  function(row, index) {
     return {
     classes: 'text-nowrap another-class',
     css: {"color": "blue", "font-size": "50px"}
     };
 }
});
```

read the docs here http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/